# How to keep selected disabled button to look like selected button but dimmed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I put this code to confirm my suspicion

```
if (self.Ihatethis.selected) {
    self.Ilikethis.enabled=!self.Ilikethis.enabled;
    return;
}
```

So basically one button will toggle enable state for the other.

Now I already have:

```
[self.Ilikethis setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-recommend-active"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[self.Ihatethis setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-dislike-active"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

somewhere in viewDidLoad.

The result is when button is disabled, it looks like the normal button except that it's dimmed.

When button is disabled, I want the selected button to keep looking like it's selected state.

So how would I do so?

Comment: Please change your photo..

Comment: Try UIControlStateSelected when you want to selected...otherwise use UIControlStateNormal .

Comment: The avatar looks nice, wing wing <3 You are not forced to have your own photo as avatar?

Comment: No, its luking cool @Sharen Eayrs...Plz don't change...

Comment: @Vishal.. bad boy Vishal.. :)

Comment: Aczhually what makes you think it's not my own photo? Am I sensing sexism here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't disable your button. Make its userInteraction set to NO

```
btn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Hope it helps you..